# ACR task for cleanup avoiding specific tags giving syntax error

Tags: bash, azure, syntax-error, task, acr

I'm trying to create ACR tasks that would run [`acr purge` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auto-purge#use-the-purge-command) to cleanup of ACR registry.

Here is a command for ACR cleanup of 3 repositories, except those with the tag `latest` :

```
az acr run --cmd 'acr purge --filter '^dev\\/(repo1|repo2|repo_3)$:^((?!latest).)*$' --ago 5d --keep 4 --untagged --dry-run'  -c /dev/null -r acrregistry1
```

But the command is returning the error:

```
-bash: !latest: event not found
```

Then I tried changing the command to consider images with any tag:

```
az acr run --cmd 'acr purge --filter '^dev\\/(repo1|repo2|repo_3)$:.*' --ago 5d --keep 4 --untagged --dry-run'  -c /dev/null -r acrregistry1
```

That again returns an error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Is this a problem that I'm missing something very basic with bash?

Or is it something related to `az` that doesn't support negative lookahead in regex for tags?

Installed version of azure-cli : `2.53.1 *`

Comment: `-bash: !latest: event not found` indicates the history feature of the `bash` shell trying to process your command. Escape any `!` chars in your code or arguments with `\!`. Good luck.

Comment: Try this `az acr run --cmd 'acr purge --filter '\''^dev\\/(repo1|repo2|repo_3)$:^((?!latest).)*$'\'' --ago 5d --keep 4 --untagged' -r acrregistry1 /dev/null` and [output](https://i.imgur.com/OrgfxVH.png)

Comment: Thanks @Imran . That almost worked. I have added that in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Imran, the solution you proposed worked well after also removing one `\` from `dev\\/` to make it `dev\/`.

```
az acr run --cmd 'acr purge --filter '\''^dev\/(repo1|repo2|repo_3)$:^((?!latest).)*$'\'' --ago 5d --keep 4 --untagged --dry-run' -c /dev/null -r acrregistry1
```

One extra backslash was required when [Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/container_registry_task) was used to create ACR tasks that make use of the `acr purge` command. Terraform requires the `\` of the cmd to be escaped using another `\`.

Via the command line, you can create an ACR task that used `acr purge` command like this:

```
az acr task create --cmd 'acr purge --filter '\''^dev\/(repo1|repo2|repo_3)$:^((?!latest).)*$'\'' --ago 5d --keep 4 --untagged --dry-run' -c /dev/null -r acrregistry1 --name testacrtask4
```

**Note:** Try decoding the value of the **encodedStep** parameter found in the result JSON. Verify if the cmd is properly rendered or not.

You can run the task as follows and verify the command is working as intended:

```
az acr task run -r acrregistry1 --name testacrtask4
```

If you are targeting a completely private ACR (accessible through private endpoints), you would need to follow the steps mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/allow-access-trusted-services#example-acr-tasks) (with ACR push role to the system-managed identity of the task) to make it work.

**Note:**

The regular expression `^((?!latest).)*$` matches string **that doesn't contain** `latest`. That means, when using this regexp for tags in the `acr purge` command, it will not remove images with `latest`, `dev-latest`, and `latest-dev`. If you want to avoid only the tags that are exactly equal to `latest`, use this regexp  instead: `^((?!^latest$).)*$`  or `^(?!^latest$).*$`.